# With TSQL, Get right part of a string starting 60th character, but not breaking up the word

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, substring

I am trying to break up long strings (> 60 characters) into two pieces, but keeping the integrity of the word that has the 60th character.

For example, for the string `one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen`, the letter `l` in the word `twelve` is the 60th character, so I would like to break up the string to be

`one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven`

and

`twelve thirteen fourteen`

So far, focusing on just getting the right part of the string, I can use `REVERSE()` to get the whole last word

```
DECLARE @Input varchar(100)
SET @Input = 'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen'

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(@Input, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@Input)) - 1))) AS LastWholeWord
    ,  @Input           AS UnalteredString
    ,  LEN(@Input)      AS LengthOfString
    ,  LEFT(@Input, 60) AS First60
```

Now, my thought was that I could just restrict the last `REVERSE()` to the first 60 characters by putting a `LEFT(@Input, 60)` in, as such `LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(@Input, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(@Input, 60))) - 1)))`

but that doesn't seem to give the desired result. I would love it if someone could point me in the correct direction!!

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @divingSpaceChar INT =
LEN(SUBSTRING(@Input,0, 60)) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Input,0, 60))) + 1

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, 0, @divingSpaceChar) AS leftString
SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Input,  @divingSpaceChar, LEN(@input))) AS rightString
```

Get the index of the last space character in the first 60 chars of the substring.
Get the substring from that last charindex...

Without additional variables, you can do:

```
SELECT
RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(SUBSTRING(@Input,0, 60)) 
- CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Input,0, 60)))+ 1, LEN(@input)))) AS RightPart,
RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Input, 0, LEN(SUBSTRING(@Input,0, 60))
- CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Input,0, 60)))+ 1))) AS LeftPart
```

Comment: This does indeed answer my question--thank you! However, I used the first iteration of your response because I will not actually be using variables in the code. Can you edit your answer to include `RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(SUBSTRING(@Input,0, 60)) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Input,0, 60)))+ 1, LEN(@input)))) AS RightPart`

and 

`RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Input, 0, LEN(SUBSTRING(@Input,0, 60)) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Input,0, 60)))+ 1))) AS LeftPart`

Comment: yup, just put that there for clarity

Answer (score 0):

What about using regular expression, looks much cleaner..

*(I'll show the syntax using Presto, but I assume pretty similar to other SQLs)*

The regex: `'(.{1,60})(?= )(.*)'`.
Note in the query: the $1, $2 to show each part of the string..

```
SELECT regexp_replace('one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen',
                  '(.{1,60})(?= )(.*)', '$1') part1,
       regexp_replace('one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen',
                  '(.{1,60})(?= )(.*)', '$2') part2


-----
Results
part1                                                    part2
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven  twelve thirteen fourteen
```

Comment: Interesting. I might play around with that just for fun. Just for posterity, the part 2 answer needs to be "twelve thirteen fourteen", and the part 1 should not have "twelve"